# Consuming micro service from mobile client or browser

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, service-discovery

I was learning micro service concepts  in spring cloud and its service discovery mechanism. What I understand is all service providers register themselves in service discovery. Consumers get endpoint details for required service from discovery server and then connect to the endpoint. It's all works fine when consumer is a component built on spring cloud.

When we need to consume a service from Mobile client like react native, what should be the approach? Are we supposed to use a static endpoint which receives all requests from mobile and invoke actual endpoint using inputs from service discovery server?

Comment: That's what an API gateway is for

Comment: Thanks spencergibb. Another topic to learn now.